# Incorrect display of post titles in WordPress admin panel

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

### In the WordPress admin panel, the title of the posts is not displayed properly.

**Post titles are compressed (below each other)**

---

[image: Problem not displaying the title of the post correctly]

Comment: Is post titles fetched correctly (Check them with chrome dev tools) ? Maybe the problem is from CSS

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Stackoverflow.  This question needs more details so that someone can actually help you.  You should consider reading [ask] and [mre] and [Why not post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have too many columns on the page. Try to uncheck some of them.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ,problem solved. I was looking for this option that I was able to find based on the image you submitted. The path of this menu: `posts > All Posts > Screen Option `

Comment: Awesome. Happy to help :D